# 'testArray was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++

This is an assignment i am working on for class. To make a long story short i am attempting to call the `allocate()` function in main to execute. I keep getting the error that `testArray` was not declared in this scope". I am a bit confused, If my return statement is being called through my function than how can it not be in scope? I hope this is making sense, I am confusing myself with these pointers and functions. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* allocate(int&);

int* allocate(int &numOfScores)
{

    int *testArray;

    //prompt user for scores
    cout << "How many test scores would\n";
    cout << "you like to process: " << endl;
    cin >> numOfScores;

    //dynammically allocate an arrray to hold the scores
    testArray = new int[numOfScores];

    //get the scores from user
    for(int count = 0; count < numOfScores; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Score: " << endl;
        cin >> testArray[count];
    }


    //release the memory that was allocated for *ptr 
    delete [] testArray;
    testArray = 0;

    return testArray;
}

int main()
{   

    allocate(testArray);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I see! Thank you all for the suggestions, I thought since i was calling the allocate() function it would return regardless of scope, i understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are refering to testArray as though it was defined in the current function what you actually need is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* allocate(int&);

int* allocate(int &numOfScores)
{

    int *testArray;

    //prompt user for scores
    cout << "How many test scores would\n";
    cout << "you like to process: " << endl;
    cin >> numOfScores;

    //dynammically allocate an arrray to hold the scores
    testArray = new int[numOfScores];

    //get the scores from user
    for(int count = 0; count < numOfScores; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Score: " << endl;
        cin >> testArray[count];
    }


    //release the memory that was allocated for *ptr 
    delete [] testArray;
    testArray = 0;

    return testArray;
}

int main()
{   
    int* testArray;
    int numberOfScores;
    testArray=allocate(numberOfScores);
    delete[] testArray;
    return 0;
}
```

However I would discourage this style of coding. You should looking into using std::vectors.

for example

```
size_t nun_scores;  
std::cin >> nun_scores;
std::vector<int> scores(num_scores);
//so on
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Doesn't calling `delete [] testArray` within `allocate` free the memory for the array?  Then you are returning a pointer to unallocated space which has undefined behavior... right?

Comment: @Mosby: It only becomes undefined behaviour if the pointer is dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

`testArray` is a local variable inside `allocate`, and doesn't exist and is not visible inside `main`. If you want to create a local variable inside `main` that will be assigned the return value of `allocate`, you'd do it this way:

```
int numberOfScores;
int* testArray = allocate(numberOfScores);
```

But realise that since you have `delete[]`ed the array inside `allocate` and set it to 0, the `testArray` you create in `main` will point to `NULL`. You'd better not set it to 0 inside `allocate` and `delete[]` it at the end of `main` rather than inside `allocate`, or if you can, use `std::vector` to avoid having to do manual memory management.

Also, you might want to make sure that `cin >> numOfScores` did not fail, and that if it succeeded, `numOfScores` is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the allocate() function with a variable testArray which you never created.  The fact that a variable of the same name may exist in another function (i.e. scope) does not matter--it doesn't exist in main(), nor globally.